# How to check if at least one method return true?

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, java-8

I have an Interface with method:

```
boolean isForbidden();
```

and few implementations, which are Spring Components.
In used class, I autowirding all of them and I want to check if at least one of them returning true. How can I do that? Is there a simply way to check it?

Interface:

```
public interface ForbiddenChecker {

   boolean isForbidden();

}
```

Class:

```
@Autowired
private List<ForbiddenChecker> validators;
```

And I want to create a method something like:

```
public boolean shouldInvokeProcess() {
   // at least one component return true
}
```

What might the body of this method look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like I'm missing something here...

```
public boolean shouldInvokeProcess() {
  for (var checker : validators) if (checker.isForbidden()) return false;
  return true;
}
```

If you're one of those 'ooh! shiny new hammer!' folks:

```
public boolean shouldInvokeProcess() {
  return !validators.stream().anyMatch(ForbiddenChecker::isForbidden);
}

Both seem about equally fine, here, and trivial.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, surely you can just iterate over the list of validators, calling each ones "isForbidden" method. If one returns true then return true from "shouldInvokeProcess"